# Resetting form using formKey.currentState.reset() not working

Tags: forms, validation, flutter

I am creating a form that includes an email address, password and its submit button. When I tried to reset the form using formKey.currentState.reset it didn't work. Can you help me out

```
class App extends StatelessWidget{
Widget build(context){
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Log Me In!',
    home: Scaffold(
          body: LoginScreen(),
    )
  );
}

}





class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreenState createState() => LoginScreenState();
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Form(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            emailField(),
             passwordField(),
             Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),),
              submitButton(),
          ],
        )));
  }



Widget submitButton(){

   return RaisedButton(
     child: Text('Submit'),
     color: Colors.blueGrey,
     onPressed: (){
       formKey.currentState.reset();
     },
   );
 }
```

I expect the email address and password to be reset. No error messages.

Comment: be sure to accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon if it solved your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what your issue is, you needed to set the `key` property of the `Form` widget with the variable you created. eg. `key: formKey`

Below is a complete code of your `LoginScreenState` class to fix the problem:

```
class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Form(
        key: formKey, // you missed out on this!!!
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            emailField(),
            passwordField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),),
            submitButton(),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }

  Widget submitButton(){
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Submit'),
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      onPressed: (){
        formKey.currentState.reset();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for being sure of no exception raised if state not exist (for any reason), be sure to make `formKey.currentState?.reset();` call :) (with ? after currentState)